# Use find to locate dot files up to 7 characters long

Tags: shell, find

I tried this:

```
find . \( -name ".?" -o -name ".??" -o -name ".???" -o -name ".????" -o -name ".?????" -o -name ".??????" \)
```

But it didn't work

Comment: Try removing the braces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your command works fine. But there are shorter alternatives. E.g.:

```
find . -name '.*' ! -name '.???????*'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it your way, by explicitly putting all the possible combinations. But that is cumbersome when you have many, or when you have to modify it. There are simpler, parameterized ways, to do that.

One way would be using regular expressions:

```
find . -regextype posix-egrep -regex ".*/\..{1,7}"
```

If your find does not support regular expressions, another easy way would be to filter the output of find with the help of awk:

```
find . -name ".*" | awk -F"/" 'length($NF)<8 {print}'
```